# Making a streched box (or circle) with Compose and MotionLayout

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I am trying to get a good understanding of how to use `MotionLayout` in Jetpack Compose.

At this state, I believe to have a basic understanding of how the `MotionLayout` works, by having a `MotionScene` (defined in a .json5 file) set to the `MotionLayout` and then apply a `Modifier.layoutId` to all the Composables, which should have an effect in the animation.

What I am trying to do, is to have a circle, which should stretch out on the X-axis, left side first (for maybe 2-300 ms) then have the right side follow along awards the left (for 2-300 ms), so that it will be a full circle once again - Just at a different position.

An example of what I wish to have, is an animation similar to the three images here.
[image: Example of how the animation should work]

Sadly I haven't been able to do that yet. In the `Transitions` part of the `MotionScene`, I have played around with `scaleX`, which made the circle misshaped and stretched out to both sides at the same time. And `translationX` which ofc, just moves the entire circle instead of just a part of it.

My current implementation looks like this:

**Composable**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun AnimationScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene).readBytes().decodeToString()
    }
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Column {
        MotionLayout(
            motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
            progress = progress,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .layoutId("row_container")
            ) { }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topEnd = 25.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 25.dp,
                            topStart = 25.dp,
                            bottomStart = 25.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .layoutId("circle")
            )
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.height(32.dp))

        Slider(
            value = progress,
            onValueChange = {
                progress = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**motion_scene.json5**

```
{
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      circle: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        start: ['logo_pic', 'start', 0],
        end: ['logo_pic', 'end', 0],
        top: ['logo_pic', 'top', 0],
        bottom: ['logo_pic', 'bottom', 0]
      },
    },
    end: {
      circle: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        start: ['logo_pic', 'start', 0],
        end: ['logo_pic', 'end', 0],
        top: ['logo_pic', 'top', 0],
        bottom: ['logo_pic', 'bottom', 0],
      },
    },
  },
  Transitions: {
    default: {
      from: 'start',
      to: 'end',
      pathMotionArc: 'startHorizontal',
      KeyFrames: {
        KeyAttributes: [
          {
            target: ['circle'],
            frames: [0, 50, 80, 100],
            scaleX: [1, 1, 2, 2],

            //translationX: [0, 0, 0, -150]
          },
        ],
        KeyPosition: [
          {
            target: ['circle'],
            percentWidth: 20
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully it all comes down to my just being new to this framework, and someone just says, "Easy! You just need to...".
Any suggestions on, how I would make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a simple way to do this with motionlayout
Because the start and end are the same size.
But you can add a middle and play some trick with progress.
It was coded this way to avoid a few bugs in the latest release.

[image: demo of motion]

```kotlin
public const val motionSceneStr = """
{
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      circle: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
        bottom: ['parent', 'bottom', 0]
      },
    },
    
   middle: {
      circle: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 40,
        start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
        end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
        bottom: ['parent', 'bottom', 0],
      },
    },
   
    end: {
      circle: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
        top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
        bottom: ['parent', 'bottom', 0],
      },
    },
  },
  Transitions: {
      part2: {   from: 'middle',   to: 'end'  }
      part1: {   from: 'middle',       to: 'start'   }
  }
}
""";


@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun AnimationScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {motionSceneStr }
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Column {
        MotionLayout(
            motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
            progress = if (progress<0.5) 1-progress*2  else progress*2-1,
            transitionName = if (progress<0.5f) "part1" else "part2",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .layoutId("row_container")
            ) { }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topEnd = 25.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 25.dp,
                            topStart = 25.dp,
                            bottomStart = 25.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .layoutId("circle")
            )
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.height(32.dp))

        Slider(
            value = progress,
            onValueChange = {
                progress = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is differently a helpful example :)